# Authorization header not working in nativescript

Tags: angular, django-rest-framework, angular2-nativescript

I am making a request to a RestAPI made on DjangoRestFramework using NativeScript for Angular with the next code:

```
getImages() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic YWRtaW5jaHVwaXRvczpDaHVwaXRvczIwMTguKg==');

    return this.http.get(
      Config.apiUrl + "images",
      { headers: headers}
    )
    .map(response => response.json())
    .catch(this.handleErrors);
  }
```

However, the API sends the next message:

> {"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}

I have tested the request using PostMan an it works so I don't know what I'm missing. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Could you please update your api url also? It is hard to debug with the information you provided.

Comment: Can you give more information ? By example what is the output on server side ? What do you see in your dev console ? Give more details please.

Comment: I am also having the same issue.  I was able to get it to work with iOS by putting it in the URL (i.e. https://username:password@domain.com/) however this does not work in android.  When I looked at Fiddler the authorization header is not there when I try to add it as a header.